# WHERE condition not related to NULL, eliminates rows with NULL values

Tags: mysql, join

```
CREATE TABLE players (
  `userID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`userID`));

CREATE TABLE opponents (
  `userID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`userID`));

CREATE TABLE relationship (
  `user1_userID` INT NOT NULL,
  `user2_userID` INT NOT NULL,
  `blocked` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY (`user1_userID`, `user2_userID`));

INSERT INTO players (`name`) 
VALUES ('alpha'), ('beta'), ('gamma'), ('delta');

INSERT INTO opponents (`name`) 
VALUES ('alpha'), ('beta');

INSERT INTO relationship (`user1_userID`, `user2_userID`, `blocked`)
VALUES (1,2, 1), (1,3, 1), (1,4, 1), (2, 1, 1), (2,3, 1), (3,4, 1);

SELECT o.userID, o.name, ur.*
FROM opponents o
LEFT JOIN players p
    ON (o.userID != p.userID)
LEFT JOIN relationship ur
    ON ((ur.user1_userID = p.userID AND ur.user2_userID = o.userID) OR 
       (ur.user1_userID = o.userID AND ur.user2_userID = p.userID)) 
-- WHERE (ur.blocked != 1)
```

If I don't put the `WHERE` condition, I see a `NULL` row for relationship columns i.e. beta has not blocked delta.

But when I uncomment the `WHERE` condition, I was expecting only this row to remain. But it also gets eliminated. Why does that happen and how to write the query correctly ? Thanks.

Comment: Change the where clause to WHERE ur.blocked IS NULL

Comment: Using (ur.blocked IS NULL) would be temporary workaround. Let's say there is another row in the result, whose (ur.blocked is 0). We want all rows that have NULL or 0 (basically != 1). The real question is why does (ur.blocked != 1) eliminate the row where ur.blocked is NULL ?

Comment: The reason it is NULL is because there wasn't a matching row in the join. Use WHERE ur.blocked IS NULL OR ur.blocked <> 1.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL unlike in some programming languages where you can use an equal (`=`) elvaluator to test for `NULL`, in `ANSI SQL` you cannot and must `IS NULL` or opposite `IS NOT NULL` to evaluate for null values. This mean if you use an `=` evaluation and a row has a `NULL` value it won't even be considered, at least this is the case for `MySQL InnoDB`, some `RMBDS` handle them slightly different.

Now for your specific case you could alter you query like this to get the desired result

```
SELECT o.userID, o.name, ur.*
FROM opponents o
LEFT JOIN players p
    ON (o.userID != p.userID)
LEFT JOIN relationship ur
    ON ((ur.user1_userID = p.userID AND ur.user2_userID = o.userID) OR 
       (ur.user1_userID = o.userID AND ur.user2_userID = p.userID)) 
WHERE (ur.blocked != 1 OR ur.blocked IS NULL)
```

**UPDATED**

becaue I guess sometimes I'm not the best explainer and at the end of the day I'm just some guy on the internet here are some links to mysql documentation that should help clear things up a little. Hopefully the help answer "the real question"

[Comparison Functions and Oporators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html)

[Working With NULL VALUES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html)

[Problems With NULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-null.html)

**EDIT**

I guess to explain my self better, the value `NULL` cannot be evaluated by a boolean operator because `NULL` is the absence of a value, and since it has no value it can neither be 1 nor 0. so in any boolean evaluation it will never return false, for example `NULL=1` and `NULL!=1` are both false. Now I also want to mention so possible alternative solutions because in databases handling nulls correctly is very important if you want to get accurate information from your database.

in `MySQL` there are 2 functions that you could use in addition to `!=` that would give you desired results.

```
COALESCE(ur.blocked,0) != 1
```

`COALESCE(value, ...)` can be given many values and will return the first Non-NULL value starting from left and evaluating right. So in your case that would evaluate `NULL` as `0`, which would not equal `1` and would return your missing record.

```
IFNULL(ur.blocked,0) != 1
```

`IFNULL(Value1, Value2)` this function will return the first if it is not `NULL` and return the second value if the first value is `NULL`

Hopefully this will help you handle `NULL` values in the future.

Comment: The real question is why does (ur.blocked != 1) eliminate the row where ur.blocked is NULL ? Your answer talks about why (ur.blocked = NULL) doesn't work in MySQL

Comment: I guess to try to sum up what I was trying to say in mysql InnoDB when there is a field that has a null value, and that field is being limited based on an `=` evaluator in the where clause it will remove all records where that field is null because it cannot be evaluated by the `=` or in this case the `!=`